# What to do when Layout Gravity not available/being suggested under any type of view

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-gravity

When I tried to add - android:layout_gravity inside android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
There is neither any option inside the design mode & when I tried to write the code it was displaying incorrect

After researching I found that Android Studio does this sometimes. The answer is actually quite simple.

This is the .xml file

```
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_gravity="start"
    >


</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: Its a question that has been answered by me :) I was stuck upon it for some hours, but later found that the answer was quite simple. But nobody has mentioned this over any platform

Answer (score 0):

This below method is quite simple and thus can be applied to various other same type of errors. Where you generally get confused is when you are **typing the code it turns red**, but do not stop. When you complete the line of code the compiler or Android Studio displays no error.

Actually this happens in Android Studio many a times. It doesn't provide the auto hints also it underlines the code in red. But only while typing. **

> Once you complete the code the compiler accepts it

** :)